# Can IO.File.Exists be use to check if a server is up in .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, io, server

I am creating a service that creates a text file that is read remotely by other software (this file is created on multiple servers),

When the file needs to be read I attempt to read it from a defined primary server and if I can't I assume the server is down or not responding and then attempt to get it from the secondary server,

Currently I perform an IO.File.Exists check on the file on the primary server and if this returns true I read the file, if not I perform the same check on the secondary server.

```
Dim filepath as String

If IO.File.Exists("\\<Primary server>\<Folder>\<file>") Then
    filepath = "\\<Primary server>\<Folder>\<file>")
Else
    filepath = string.empty
End if

If not filepath is string.empty then
    If IO.File.Exists("\\<Secondary server>\<Folder>\<file>") Then
        filepath = "\\<Secondary server>\<Folder>\<file>")
    Else
        filepath = string.empty
    End if
End if
```

Is this check enough to establish whether the server is available or should I be performing further tests?

Thanks

Comment: You have some redundant code. Try to think about to add your servers to a list an loop through that list until you downloaded a file successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your needs, this should be ok. But be sure, you do not't directly check wether the server is available, because if you do not have any permission, you check will also fail. Or if the server is available, but the directory/file does not exists, your check will even fail.

Answer (score 0):

This could works if file sharing is active.
Else you might need to find some other way to read the file.

client <-> server application